# Python Dataframe: grouping by date and summing by type

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe whereby I want to group by date (be it daily or weekly), and sum totals of two different categories

```
data = {'Date' : ['2020-08-20','2020-08-20','2020-08-21','2020-08-21',
        '2020-08-22','2020-08-22'],
        'Name' : ['Ben','Ben','Ben','Sam','Sam','Sam'],
        'Sales ($)' : [10,5,2,5,6,7]
       }

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date','Name','Sales ($)'])
```

so that it looks something like this:

```
grouped_data = {'Date' : ['2020-08-20','2020-08-21','2020-08-22'],
               'Ben' : [15,2,0],
               'Sam' : [0,5,13],
               }

df=pd.DataFrame(grouped_data, columns = ['Date','Ben','Sam'])
```

Comment: This looks a job for [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table), ``pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Date"],values=["Sales ($)"],columns=["Name"],aggfunc=[sum]).fillna(0.0)``

Comment: So... Did it work/help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First groupby `'Date'` and `'Name'`

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Name']).sum().unstack(-1).replace(
    np.nan, 0).droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
```

Then get the `sum`. `unstack` to set the names (in the last index level) to columns, `replace` the `np.nan` with zeros and finally `droplevel` to drop `'Sales ($)'` from the columns-`MultiIndex`.

The result looks like:

```
# Out:
Name         Ben   Sam
Date                  
2020-08-20  15.0   0.0
2020-08-21   2.0   5.0
2020-08-22   0.0  13.0
```

---

Assuming you want to **group by weeks or months**, I recommend parsing the `'Date'` column to `datetime`:

```
df['Date_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Now you extract your date-grouper on a weekly or monthly basis:

```
# weekly grouper
date_grouper = df['Date_dt'].dt.week
# monthly grouper
date_grouper = df['Date_dt'].dt.month
```

And use this grouper to get your weekly/monthly grouping:

```
df.groupby([date_grouper, 'Name']).sum().unstack(-1).replace(
    np.nan, 0).droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
```

Of course replacing the `'Date'` column with the new datetime date also works as well as setting it as the index. But when setting it as the index, you have to **omit accessing the `dt` attribute**, f.i. `date_grouper = df.index.week`

Parsing the date to a `datetime` also allows for using other groupers, such as `day`, `dayofweek`, `dayofyear`, `hour`, `minute`, `second`, `weekday`...

Comment: That's great, thank you. Is is possible to take this one step further - when I have months and months of data can i do the same thing but grouping by week or month? eg. using Grouper function?

Comment: You are welcome! sure, that should be easy. Could you please add some sample data for monthly grouping to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Name']).sum().reset_index()
```

If you want to add the weekly, daily frequency, first transform your date column to datetime :
`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`
Then you can add your frequency in here ( `W` for weekly and `D`for daily.. )

`df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="D"),'Name']).sum().reset_index()`